# I cant get it to open

Tags: compatibility

every time i open it it says "your graphics card or driver has limited support. it may work, but with issues. 
newer graphics drivers may be be available to improve blender support
graphics Intel Intel(R) Hd graphics 2500 4.0.0 - build 10.18.3325 i need  help i'm so confused.

Comment: Try to update your graphics driver using the [official driver from Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29473/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-15-33-?product=81501).

Comment: But then it works or not? Check all requirements https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/